# Unable to change multiple button colours on user's tap swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my project I am using 6 buttons in one screen.I want to change the button color based on user's tap and "day order value". i am getting "day order value" from server.for example user day order value is equal to 1, day1 button background color should be red if user taps on day2 button day2 button should be in blue and remaining all button background colour should be white.

Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

if user pressed on one button that particular button should be highlight with some color remaining buttons should be same color. I can able to change button color by checking each condition but I want to write in simple manner.

see the following code which i have i tried for "dayoredrvalue".

```
func UpdateButtoncolor()
    {
        let dayOrderStr  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "dayOrderStr")
        print("dayOrderStr--",dayOrderStr)

        if (dayOrderStr?.isEqual("1"))!{


            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        }else if(dayOrderStr?.isEqual("2"))!
        {
            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }else if(dayOrderStr?.isEqual("3"))!
        {
            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }else if(dayOrderStr?.isEqual("4"))!
        {
            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }else if(dayOrderStr?.isEqual("5"))!
        {
            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }else
        {
            self.day1Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day2Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day3Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day4Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day5Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.day6Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }


    }
```

Comment: Share your implemented code with us. Have you taken separate outlet for each or have taken a group outlet.?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Why don't you set white color to all buttons outside all conditions and just set the sender button color in button action? [Like this](http://pasted.co/b96780d5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per your query, It's quite simple. Just follow the following -**

**Step 1:**  Add an `UIButton` object in your viewController. Like that -

```
 var selectedButton: UIButton? = nil
```

**Step 2:** Add same button Action for all your buttons -

```
@IBAction func btnActionSelection(_ sender:UIButton){

   if(selectedButton == nil){ // No previous button was selected

    updateButtonSelection(sender)

   }else{ // User have already selected a button

      if(selectedButton != sender){ // Not the same button

            selectedButton?.backgroundColor = .clear
            updateButtonSelection(sender)
         }

   }
}
```

**Step 3:** Now, Update button selection

```
func updateButtonSelection(_ sender: UIButton){

   UserDefaults.standard.set("\(sender.tag)", forKey: "dayOrderStr")
   selectedButton = sender
   selectedButton?.backgroundColor = .green

}
```

**Step 4:** Check User selected day (For that you need to add tag on buttons from 1 to 6 respectively)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   // Check user's selected day
    if let selectedDay =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "dayOrderStr") as? String{

         debugPrint("selectedDay: "selectedDay) // Get user's selected day
         if let btn = self.view.viewWithTag(Int(selectedDay)!){

            updateButtonSelection(btn)

        }

    }

  //Other stuff
 }
```

Comment: @AmirKhan thank you. its working fine for tapping button but at the same time i need to check "dayordervalue" i updated my question please check it.

Comment: @vasuk You want to check the "dayordervalue" value at the beginning when the view is loaded?

Comment: @AmirKhan yes in viewedload in need to check

Comment: @vasuk save value in `Int` type in `UserDefaults`

Comment: @ Amir Khan thanks for your effort but when ever i am checking day order its not working there is no changes in  button colour.  day order value i am getting from the server not from users tap

Comment: @vasuk Save/Get the value in `Int` Type. If you save in `String` type and check on `Int` type it won't work.

Comment: @vasuk Get the response in `Int`, then it will work.

Comment: @vasuk, I've changed it's data type. Now it will work according to your parameter's data type.

Comment: @AmirKhan earlier ur code was working fine. but now    in viewdidload throwing error   at the line of            updateButtonSelection(btn as! UIButton).  Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1092c6ab0) to 'UIButton' (0x1092d07e0).
2018-05-30 11:39:22.950757+0530 Skcet[3132:64607] Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1092c6ab0) to 'UIButton' (0x1092d07e0).

Comment: @vasuk please buttons' tags.

Comment: didnt understand,,  viewdidload method throwing error.

Comment: @vasuk Check In storyboard whether you have given button tags or not.

Comment: i have given buttons tags properly . earlier its working fine but now its not working i didnt change anything in this code

Comment: @vasuk it's due to tagging I think.

Comment: You started tagging from 0 or 1?

Comment: i started from 1 to 6

Comment: @vasuk What are you getting from ` debugPrint("selectedDay: "selectedDay)` line?

Comment: i am getting value  .. 0 this value i m getting

Comment: @vasuk that's the reason, it's getting crashed. Because 0 is always refer to UIView itself.  `selectedDay` must be started from 1 and on. Response has been changed that's your app is getting crashed.

Comment: selectedDay value i am getting from server.

Comment: except '0' any value its working fine, once again thank you so much for spending your value time for  me .. @AmirKhan

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a demo for you using my logic:

For this you need to take a Group Outlets of your `UIButton` and assign a unique tag to each and then rest logic is described in the demo attached below.

like

```
 @IBOutlet var btnAllSelected: [UIButton]!
```

And then simple logic like this:

```
 @IBAction func btnAllClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    for button in btnAllSelected {
        if sender.tag == button.tag{
            button.isSelected = true;
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }else{
            button.isSelected = false;
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }

    if sender.tag == 1{
        print("Button 1 selected")
    }else if sender.tag == 2{
        print("Button 2 selected")
    }else if sender.tag == 3{
         print("Button 3 selected")
    }else if sender.tag == 4{
         print("Button 4 selected")
    }else if sender.tag == 5{
        print("Button 5 selected")
    }else if sender.tag == 6{
        print("Button 6 selected")
    }

}
```

> [Link to the Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_JJdzE3kmmYdbop1CGsnB5Xix9kRRV2o/view?usp=sharing)

**FYI:-** Please ignore the pods installed in it. I edited some another demo and made a one for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `New Referencing Outlet Collections` for all your `UIButtons` like this,

```
@IBOutlet var arrButtons: [UIButton]!
```

Implement only one Button tap events for all your buttons, Please find belo code.

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    arrButtons.forEach({$0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red})
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code, it uses an array of the buttons and an index:

```
let buttonArray = [day1Btn, day2Btn, day3Btn, day4Btn, day5Btn, day6Btn]
buttonArray.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = .white }
guard let dayOrderStr =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "dayOrderStr"),
    let dayOrderIndex = Int(dayOrderStr), 1...buttonArray.count ~= dayOrderIndex {
        buttonArray[dayOrderIndex-1].backgroundColor = .red
}
```

It can be still simpler if you save the value in `UserDefaults` as `Int`

Comment: buttonArray[dayOrderIndex-1].backgroundColor = .red i am getting this kind of error Variable used within its own initial value

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution among many others.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]! // link all the buttons from the storyboard

func changeColorButton(sender: UIButton) {
  // default appearance for all buttons
  for button in buttons {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
  }

  // update color only for the button clicked
  sender.backgroundColor = .orange
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        updateFocusPicture(sender: sender)
}
```